# How to make all images on an html page to be shown (using Bootstrap)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a set of images which I'd like to be visible to a user all at once, without scrolling or swiping. Resizing is ok indeed. The number of images may vary from page to page. There will be some other content on the page as well (title). I'm using Bootstrap as CSS framework, but I'm open to any solution (JS?) if needed.
For example, I have 10 images and Chrome on Android in portrait mode. The solution would arrange the images into a grid of 2 columns and 5 rows and 5x2 in the landscape, resizing accordingly. If there are 18 images, it'd show them 3x6 or 6x3 correspondingly. And so on.
Thanks!

**Update**
I suck in CSS. But I have good google-searching skills and found nothing on the topic. I've tried [container-fluid, row/col, img-responsive](http://searope.otzo.com/hu/welcome.html) combo, but it shows either 3xN or 1xN grid, depending on the width. And not all images are in the viewport.

Comment: OK... you stated objective, so what have you tried and what problems are you having achieving goal? This isn't a code writing service. Also , where is your [mcve] ?

Comment: I understand, this is not a code-writing service. But I think this is an interesting problem, a solution to which can be beneficial to many.

Comment: That is a poor excuse for expecting free code and not how this site works. You are expected to show attempts to solve problems yourself, and people here help fix your actual code when it doesn't do what is expected

Comment: I don't think it's too poor. Besides, I'm looking for the solution as we speak, and I'm going to post here, if found.